# Need someone to check my induction proof for errors

Tags: proof-verification, algorithms, induction, recurrence-relations, computer-science

I was told to solve the following recurrence relation/equation

$$T(n) = T(9n/10) + n$$

and after doing the algebra, I got the following solution

$$T(n) = 10[n - 1] $$

**note: we are assuming that T(1) = $0$**

(if you want to check the work i did to get the above, just check my previous post in my account)

Anyway, here is my induction proof...

**BASE** : $T(1) = 10[1 - 1]= 0 $

**Hypothesis**: Assume $T(k) = 10[k - 1]$

**Induction steps**: prove $T(10k/9) = 10[10k/9 - 1]$

1) $T(10k/9) = T(9n/10) + n$

I used the original recurrence equation and plugged in $10k/9$

2) $T(10k/9) = T(k) + 10k/9$

Now we plug in the hypothesis into our new equation

3) $T(10k/9) = 10[k−1] + 10k/9$

now we simplify..

4) $T(10k/9) = 10k− 10 + 10k/9$

5) $T(10k/9) = 100k/9 − 10 $

6) $T(10k/9) = 10[10k/9 - 1]$

Did I make any errors in my proof?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why can you assume $n$ must be of the form $10k/9$? You write it must be of the form $n = a^k$ but not $10k/9$...

Comment: $n = a^k$ was used in the process of getting the solution $T(n) = 10[n - 1] $ This rule only applies in getting the solution, but it is not supposed to be used in the induction process. I shouldn't have included that rule in this post.

Comment: Uh... no.  You don't want to prove T(10k/9)=10[10k/9-1].  You want to prove T(k+1) = T(k). And pluggin 10k/9 into the original gives T(10k/9) = T(90k/90) + 10k/9.  Not T(9n/10) +n$.  I can't follow your reasoning at all.

Comment: For any constant $k$ the sequence given by $T(n)=10n+k$ satisfies that $T(n)=n+T\left(\frac{9}{10}n\right)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\quad T(x)=x+T(\alpha x)\quad$ with $\vert\alpha\vert<1$. Then
, using **induction on $n$** you can show that:
$$T(x)=x+\alpha x+\cdots+\alpha^{n}x+T\left(\alpha^{n+1}x\right), \ \forall\,n\geq 1$$
$$T(x)=x(1+\alpha+\cdots+\alpha^{n})+T(\alpha^{n+1}x)
=x\frac{\ \ 1-\alpha^{n+1}}{1-\alpha}+T\left(\alpha^{n+1}x\right)$$
Suppose that $T$ is a continous function. Then taking the limit as $n$ tends to $\infty$, you get: (because $\vert\alpha\vert<1$)

$$T(x)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}x+T(0).$$

> The conclusion here is that the only continuous functions that satisfaies $T(x)=x+T(\alpha x)$ are of the form:
>   $$T(x)=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}x+T(0)$$
>   Here $T(0)$ is **any constant** you want.
>
> In particular, if you take $\alpha=\frac{9}{10}$ and $T(0):=-10$. You get $$T(x)=10(x-1).$$

Observe that the assumption $T(1)=0$ is equivalent to $T(0)=-10$.